# If $f$ is LSC, then there exist continuous $g_1\le g_2 \le \dots\to f$ pointwise everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

This is Exercise 2.22 from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. I can't prove this in the case where $f$ may take infinite values.

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space with metric $d$, and that $f:X \to [0,\infty]$ is lower semicontinuous, $f(p)<\infty$ for at least one $p \in X$. For $n=1,2,3,\dots, x \in X,$ define 
$$g_n(x)=\inf \{f(p)+nd(x,p):p\in X\}$$ and prove that 
(i) $|g_n(x)-g_n(y)| \le nd(x,y),$
(ii) $0\le g_1 \le g_2 \le \cdots \le f,$
(iii) $g_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$, for all $x \in  X$.

I can prove this in the case $f$ is finite-valued. 
(i) and (ii) are easy whether or not $f$ is finite-valued. For (iii), let $\epsilon>0,$ and for each $n$ we can choose $z_n \in X$ such that

$$ g_n(x)+\epsilon > f(z_n)+nd(x,z_n)\ge nd(x,z_n).$$ 
But $g_n(x)+\epsilon \le f(x)+\epsilon$, and it follows that $d(x,z_n)\to 0$. (**Here is where we use that $f$ is finite valued.**) Since $f$ is LSC, 
$\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(z_n)\ge f(x);$ thus $f(z_n) > f(x)-\epsilon$ eventually. But now 
$$g_n(x) > f(z_n)-\epsilon + nd(x,z_n) \ge f(z_n)-\epsilon >f(x)-2\epsilon$$ for large enough $n$. Hence we have $g_n \to f$ pointwise.

The problem is this proof only works when $f$ does not take $\infty$ for any $x$. How can I prove this in the specific case of the exercise, i.e., with only the assumption that $f(p)<\infty$ for at least one $p \in X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ be such that $f(x)=\infty$. Assume that $(g_n(x))_n$ (a nondecreasing sequence) does not go to $f(x)$. Then it is bounded by some $M$.

For each $n$, there is thus some $z_n$ such that $nd(x,z_n) \leq f(z_n)+nd(x,z_n) \leq M+1$.

Thus $z_n \rightarrow x$. Thus $ \lim\inf f(z_n) \geq f(x)=\infty$, ie $M+1 \geq f(z_n) \rightarrow \infty$. A contradiction.